# msbuild, support for out-of-source builds

Tags: msbuild

Is is possible to use MSBuild to make out-of-source builds: a build outside source directory?

This is a standard thing in some other building systems, like the [Autotools](http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/automake/VPATH-Builds.html) or [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#Out-of-source_build_trees). They are useful when you want to experiment with build options or share one source tree (which can be huge).

For those who ask why is such thing needed: With this, I could do a checkout (4GB here), make one build, revert to some specific revision and do another build without throwing away the first one. Or I can make a throw-away configuration with some custom settings without thinking much of going through all the configuration settings in VS. Or share a checkout between multiple automatic builders.

I know I can define separate configurations with different paths, but this is cumbersome (especially when working with multiple projects) and these configurations will propagate to other developers (which I would like to avoid when experimenting) with common VCS operations.

Comment: It's not quite clear what "outside source directory" means. Please describe your scenario and what you actually expect to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution could be to move your configuration stuff to a separate .target file. If you like to experiment with those you can replace the .target file with one of your choice while other developers can use the default .target configuration.

---

I'm still not sure if and why your sources are an issue since you would export them to a configurable build path. Is it because it would take too long to export your sources to a experimental build location? Could you use pre-built shared components for your experimental build?

---

I suspect that you are expiriencing limitations because you use MSBuild just as CLI for your Visual Studio solution(s). Admittedly MSBuild requires considerably effort to cater for flexible and complex requirements. Maybe a Continous Integration System like CruiseControl (just to name one) is what you are looking for because it offers ease of use and flexiblity you are acustomed from Autotools and CMake. If "free" isn't one of your requirements Team Foundation Server might be an option to drive MSBuild for you.

4GB sources is huge so any given tool will have to work around moving this much stuff to remain fast.

Comment: So, this doesn't work out of the box, and I'd have to hack the project files? Sad, both autotools and cmake can do that by default.

Comment: @liori It's still hard to imagine where your specific problems come from. As far as I gathered from the info on Autotools and CMake they let you specify a custom build and/or output location.

Comment: It is just some kind of flexibility I expect from a build system. For example I can do a checkout (4GB here), make one build, revert to some specific revision and do another build without throwing away the first one. Or I can make a throw-away configuration with some custom settings without thinking much of going through all the configuration settings in VS.